# DynamoDb: how to get the item based on a column having the highest number?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to query and get the record which has the highest version. I am confused and tried different ways to get the highest version from the database without having to query all the items and then manually finding out the max number. Is there any way? I do not know the highest version so I can't really filter on it.

```
const params = {
  TableName: 'mytable',
  KeyConditionExpression:
    'a= :hkey and begins_with(b, :roleName)',
  FilterExpression: 'Version > ?',
  ScanIndexForward: false, // true = ascending, false = descending
  Limit: 1,
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':hkey': 'a',
    ':roleName': 'abc',
    ':version': ?,
  },
};
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Global Secondary Index, whose partition key is fixed and whose sort key is the version. Then issue a query against that GSI with `ScanIndexForward=false` and `Limit=1` to get the last item, i.e. the item with the highest version number.

Comment: That will incur extra cost, right? Can't he set the version as the sort key in his table instead?

Comment: @KoustavRay Yes, it will increase cost (the cost of the GSI storage and reads/writes). No, he can't make `version` the sort key on the table - if the primary key is already composite then he can't add a sort key; if it's not composite then it's simply a partition key and it must be unique for each item (hence adding `version` as the sort key is not helpful in determining the highest version across all items).

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the explanation @jarmod